# most selected listitems

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a listbox that a user can select multiple values from . each user selection is stored in db as string e.g. (1,4,5) . each number represents a listitem . the question how can I retrieve most selected items, say five most items via sql ?

Comment: So if a user selects items 1, 4, 5 a row gets created in the db with the value '(1,4,5)' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the option, it would be better to store the user selections in a more granular way, something like a table that just matches users with single selections.  So if user 555 selected 1, 4, 5 the rows would be

```
555 1
555 4
555 5
```

Then finding out what gets selected the most would be a simple count.  Otherwise you're going to have to parse the '(1, 4, 5)' which is going to be rather ugly.  Usually not a good idea to store multiple values in a single column like that.

Comment: this means i would do multiple inserts, here 3 inserts . would not that be an overhead ?

Comment: A very reasonable overhead if you're going to be doing any kind of data manipulation/querying with user selections.  Storing everything in a single column makes doing even trivial things like finding the top selection difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert new (int) column in that table. So you could increase that number every time
when item is selected.